# Where to get Flash/Flex coding examples, a timeline example in particular?

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I'm in the process of learning Flex, but I learn best by example.  Where can I find open source examples of Flex applets?  In particular, I'm trying to reproduce the functionality of the JavaScript based Simile timeline, so a timeline example would be sweet.

Answer (score 2):

You must check out [Tour de Flex](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex/). There are >300 examples maintained by Adobe running in the AIR app.

There is a specific category called "data visualization".

Answer (score 0):

Check out flexlib.scheduling [here](http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/)